# formatting and number using Xpath and Xmldatasource

Tags: asp.net, xml, xpath

when i try to format number in asp repeater. I am using Xpath and XMl datasource. It Does not say any error, but i just keeps it, without any decimals.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptCvrInfo" OnItemDataBound="rptCvrInfo_ItemDataBound" runat="server" DataSourceID="DataSource1">
<itemtemplate>    
     <asp:Label ID="lblEquity" Text='<%# FormatAmount( XPath("Equity") )%>' runat="server" />
</itemtemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

My codebehind method

```
public static string FormatAmount(object In)
{
    Decimal amount = Decimal.Parse(In.ToString(), new NumberFormatInfo() {    NumberDecimalSeparator = "," });

    return amount.ToString();    
}
```

xmlnode from document

```
<Equity contextRef="ctx37" unitRef="DKK" decimals="-3">101015000
```

Comment: My codebehind method 
public static string FormatAmount(object In)
{
Decimal amount = Decimal.Parse(In.ToString(), new NumberFormatInfo() { NumberDecimalSeparator = "," });

return amount.ToString();

}
xmlnode from document 
<Equity contextRef="ctx37" unitRef="DKK" decimals="-3">101015000

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `101015000` is the value you want to convert to Decimal, you have to return a formatted string from you method. All you are doing now is convert it to a decimal and then send it back exactly as it was. You can return a formatted decimal as a string.

```
return string.Format("{0:N2}", amount);
```

Or inline without a method in code behind

```
<%# string.Format("{0:N2}", Convert.ToDecimal(XPath("Equity"))) %>
```

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings